# Order dict merge by previous date

Tags: python

My dict is

```
date1 = OrderedDict([('2015-04-18', (5,0)), ('2015-04-05', (33,0)), ('2015-04-15', (3,0)), ('2015-04-08', (53,0))])
date2 = OrderedDict([('2015-03-01', (0,5)), ('2015-03-05', (0,10)), ('2015-03-15', (0,13)), ('2015-03-28', (0,53))])
```

I wanted to merge this my previous month  and also in sorted 
like,

```
date = OrderedDict([('2015-03-01', (0,5)),('2015-03-28', (0,53)), ('2015-04-05', (33,10)), ('2015-04-08', (53,0), ('2015-04-15', (3,13),('2015-04-18', (5,0))])
```

Comment: what is the purpose you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] Concatanate the items (pairs) lists:

```
items = list(date1.items()) + list(date2.items())
```

[2] Sort them (correctly sorts by the first in each pair, i.e. the date string):

```
items = sorted(items)
```

[3] Back to an `OrderedDict`:

```
date = OrderedDict(items)
```

---

As a one-liner:

```
date = OrderedDict( sorted( list(date1.items()) + list(date2.items()) )  )
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to join the values of the same 'day' with the same key. For example - '2015-04-05' has all the non-zero values of 5th of all the months

Answer (score 0):

It looks like date2 values are all pre-sorted by date.  date1 values must follow for the final product.  I think the .join function will help.

This answer may help you:  [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)